# MySQL multiple if statement executions

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to be able to perform two executions in my if statement.
I am getting an error on the last semi colon:

```
If(condition)
THEN
SET table.column = table1.column;
INSERT INTO errortable (column) VALUES ("Error");
END IF;
```

This also does not work:

```
If(condition)
THEN
SET table.column = table1.column,
INSERT INTO errortable (column) VALUES ("Error");
END IF;
```

Nor this:

```
If(condition)
THEN
SET table.column = table1.column
INSERT INTO errortable (column) VALUES ("Error");
END IF;
```

Thanks

Comment: Saying what error you're getting would be helpful.

Comment: How did you run this script? Is it procedure?

Comment: 1. The error is along the lines of "Semi colon is unexpected"
2. I ran the statement directly in the editor in phpMyAdmin
3. Yes- essentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"BEGIN ... END syntax is used for writing compound statements", according to the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/begin-end.html

Also, i believe the parentheses matter: "There is also an IF()function, which differs from the IFstatement described here. See Section 12.4, “Control Flow Functions”. The IF statement can have THEN, ELSE, and ELSEIF clauses, and it is terminated with END IF." -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html

Answer (score 1):

You are using [If()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function instead of [If statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html). Remove the brackets from the condition.